# jsPDF addHTML doesn't render the body properly on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, jspdf

I am using jsPDF to convert the body into pdf. It works perfectly fine on the desktop browser but if i try it using browsers on mobile devices it doesnt work that well as it becomes blurry. Has anyone experienced this kind of problem if so I would appreciate your input into how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Include the following Scripts in your project:

- `jspdf.js`
- `jspdf.plugin.from_html.js`
- `jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js`
- `jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js`

Comment: I included those scripts now i get an error saying doc.addHTML is not a function